# Laravel: accessing collection values inside blade template

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

So I did just like suggested me and replaced the multiple queries with a single one in order to improve performance, problem is now I'm getting the following message error:
"
 ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined index: appName  "

First my migration so you can see data structure:

```js
Schema::create('globals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('displayName');
            $table->string('value')->nullable();
            $table->integer('intValue')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        
        DB::table('globals')->insert([
            'name' => 'appName',
            'displayName' => 'Nombre de la aplicación',
            'value' => config('globals.appName'),
        ]);
```

This is how I gather the globals:

```js
$globals = Globals::all()->pluck('name', 'value', 'intValue'); 
$view->with('globals', $globals);
```

I want to access the data in my blade template by 'name' and their corresponding value, like this:

```js
{{ $globals['appName']['value'] }}
```

This is what I get after doing: {{ dd($globals) }}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNOqk.png

It appears they are backwards? how can I fix this?

Comment: what do you want when you call config('globals.appName')?  Do you have a config file called globals.php ? who defines an array containing the key appName ?

Comment: what do you mean by they are backwards ? order is not right ?

Comment: @simonecosci in this case globals.appName is just a string, I want to access the values like this: $globals['appName']['value'] or similar

Comment: `$globals = Globals::all()->pluck('value', 'name')->all(); ` allows to access as `$value = $globals['appName'];` // name will be the key

Answer (score 0):

change

`$globals = Globals::all()->pluck('name', 'value', 'intValue');`

to

`$globals = Globals::all()->keyBy('name')->toArray();`

and

```
{{ $globals['appName']['value'] }}
{{ $globals['appName']['displayName'] }}
{{ $globals['appName']['intValue'] }}
```

will be available

Answer (score 0):

If you pluck the collection like this

```
$globals = Globals::all()->pluck('value', 'name');
```

You will end up getting an array of `['name' => 'value']` elements

So you can access it like `{{ $globals['appName'] }}` in your view

Lets for example say you will insert another db record

```
DB::table('globals')->insert([
    'name' => 'configName',
    'displayName' => 'Something',
    'value' => 'config value',
]);
```

You should be able to access this property in your view with just a name like

```
{{ $globals['configName'] }}
```